# Will youtube income be haram? if there maybe 2 or 3 ads shown that are haram?

Tags: halal-haram, sharia

So as i know. YouTube income by ads is halal as long as it's doesn't contain any haram thing. And we can do that by selecting specific ads. but however, It is kinda impossible (From my knowledge) to block all the haram ads. **There might be shown few 1 or 2 ads sometimes that haram. Because of this will my whole income be haram? because of one or two haram ads?**

Comment: why you  think it will be halal ?

Comment: I don't know. I did some quick research and the answer seems unclear. Personally I'd avoid it unless I was pretty sure. One site I saw recommended donating the income without intention of sadqah. Allah knows best.

Answer (score -2):

salaam,
Of course it is not haram. It's like your own business, and you are selling your content (just like restaurants that post ads on their menus.)
Hope that helps.
Michelle

Comment: How do you come to such certainty?